# Add class to list item if it's child image width is < 667

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list of images witch are inside a list tag. I want to add a class to the list tag via jQuery, if image's(that are inside list tag) width is smaller than 667px

```
jQuery('.basic-gallery li').each(function() {
 if(jQuery(this).children().attr('width') < 700) {
  jQuery(this).parent().addClass('half');
};
});


<ul class="basic-gallery text-center">

<li><img class="attachment-large" width="667" height="1000" src="/example.jpg" style="max-height: 917px; width: auto; height: auto;"></img></li>
<li><img class="attachment-large" width="667" height="1000" src="/example.jpg" style="max-height: 917px; width: auto; height: auto;"></img></li>
<li><img class="attachment-large" width="667" height="1000" src="/example.jpg" style="max-height: 917px; width: auto; height: auto;"></img></li>
<li><img class="attachment-large" width="667" height="1000" src="/example.jpg" style="max-height: 917px; width: auto; height: auto;"></img></li>
```

How is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the width from the `img` tag properties:

```
$('.basic-gallery li').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('img').attr('width') < 667) {
        $(this).closest('ul').addClass('half');
    };
});
```

Otherwise, following @Anri's answer above, you can get the width of the image:

```
$('.basic-gallery li').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('img').width() < 667) {
        $(this).closest('ul').addClass('half');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change `jQuery(this).children().attr('width')` to `jQuery(this).children().width`

Comment: look above please I posted the link